# Time series Forecasting with Daily values

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I am doing forecasting with auto.Arima with uni-variate data but my forecast is not correct. I have used all the steps correctly but the point forecast value is not coming out to be right. Please help me.

Here is my data:

```
s <- read.csv(url('https://ondemand.websol.barchart.com/getHistory.csv?apikey=c3122f072488a29c5279680b9a2cf88e&symbol=zs*1&type=dailyNearest&backAdjust=false&startDate=20100201'))
```

Here is my code:

```
data <- s[c(3, 7)]
summary(data)
data1.ts <- zoo(data[,2], seq(from = as.Date("2010-02-01"), to = as.Date("2022-05-13"), by = 1))
autoplot(data1.ts)
```

Arima Model:

```
fit_arima <- auto.arima(data1.ts, stepwise = FALSE, approximation = FALSE, trace = TRUE)
print(summary(fit_arima)) 
checkresiduals(fit_arima)


forecast_Arima <- forecast(fit_arima, h = 1)
forecast_Arima
```

Foreacst Value:

```
      Point Forecast   Lo 80    Hi 80   Lo 95    Hi 95
19126       976.4357 949.874 1002.997 935.813 1017.058
```

## Little update:

I have tried to load the data as a ts object and have got the accurate Point forecast value but, my forecast year is not correct. The one-step-ahead forecasting is giving me value for the year 2021 but my end date is 2022-05-13. I just want to correct the year. This is new code:

```
ts_soy <- ts(data[,2], start = c(2010-02-01), frequency = 214)
autoplot(ts_soy)

fit_arima <- auto.arima(ts_soy) 
print(summary(fit_arima)) 
checkresiduals(fit_arima)

forecast_Arima <- forecast(fit_arima, h = 1)
forecast_Arima


      Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
2021.472         1646.5 1625.071 1667.929 1613.727 1679.273
```

Comment: Why is your forecast not correct? Can you post the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, and the reason is that your `data1.ts` contains too much data. You are trying to get rid of the weekends to create a continuous timeseries (aka timeseries without gaps). The principle is correct but you are exceeding the amount of records you have by 1388 records. Since R tends to recycle values, you get closing prices from the early years again and this influences the `arima` function.

You can do something like create a timeseries starting from the earliest date and to is this date + the number of records - 1

```
data.ts <- zoo(data[,2], seq(from = as.Date("2010-02-01"), 
                             to = as.Date("2010-02-01") + 3096, 
                             by = 1))

fit_ar <- forecast::auto.arima(data.ts, stepwise = FALSE, approximation = FALSE)

forecast::forecast(fit_ar, h = 1)

      Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
17738       1648.129 1626.759 1669.499 1615.446 1680.812
```

This is one of the reasons why I prefer to use fable, I can inspect the data better.

```
library(fpp3)
library(fable.prophet)

fit <- data %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% # create index to use otherwise timeseries has gaps
  tsibble(index = id) %>%
  model(naive = NAIVE(close),
        arima = ARIMA(close, stepwise = FALSE, approximation = FALSE),
        )

forecast(fit, h = 1)
# A fable: 2 x 4 [1]
# Key:     .model [2]
  .model    id        close .mean
  <chr>  <dbl>       <dist> <dbl>
1 naive   3098 N(1646, 280) 1646.
2 arima   3098 N(1649, 278) 1649.

# prophet needs dates and can handle weekends
prophet_fit <- data %>% 
  mutate(tradingDay = ymd(tradingDay)) %>%
  tsibble() %>%
  model(prophet_model = prophet(close))

 
forecast(prophet_fit, h = 1)
# A fable: 1 x 4 [1D]
# Key:     .model [1]
  .model        tradingDay        close .mean
  <chr>         <date>           <dist> <dbl>
1 prophet_model 2022-05-14 sample[5000] 1657.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is what I was looking for this is perfect, btw I have edited my question with some new line of codes which did get me the accurate forecast value but not the accurate year. Please see the little update part. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @M.TalhaBinAsif, your frequency is off. It might work for 1 year, but not the whole set. You're better of forecasting on an id basis and then assigning a date to it, e.g. combining it with a calendar.

Comment: just one more thing. How can I check the summary, Diagnostic measures and residual plot for the prophet model! @phiver.

Comment: @M.TalhaBinAsif, full details in [Forecasting: principles and practice, 3rd edition](https://otexts.com/fpp3/). e.g. residuals plot: `augment(prophet_fit) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = .fitted, y = .resid)) +
  geom_point() + labs(x = "Fitted", y = "Residuals")`

Comment: Thanks a lot, dear. Really appreciate that plus the link was very helpful. I am gonna download this whole book and memorize it to my bone :). @phiver